# Visa for Canada from USA for a Bangladeshi

Tags: visas, canada, bangladeshi-citizens

I have B1/B2 visa, 5 years multiple entry visa taken from my home country Bangladesh. I have come to USA for the first time in February 2014 with my baby of 4 years old. Now I want to visit Canada as a tourist. Is it possible to take visa for Canada for me & my child from USA?

Comment: It's definitely possible. One of my friends has done it without any issues. I myself have been to the EU from the US. Would you mention which city are you from?

Comment: This website will tell you whether you need a visa for Canada. http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/cometocanada.asp

Comment: @AdityaSomani-Thanks for your information. I am from Dhaka, Bangladesh & now I am in Florida in my cousin's house who is a US citizen. Actually, one Pakistani lawyer in New York informed one of my friends that I need to go back to Bangladesh to apply for US Visa. Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are already aware that you do need a visitor visa for Canada ([you wouldn't need the visa if you were a permanent resident of U.S.A](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&&NA=BD&AR=US&EM=US&DE=CA&VT=US&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=MS&subuser=MS)).

[This page on the Government of Canada site confirms that citizens of Bangladesh need a visa to visit Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Bangladesh).

It also states:

[image]

> Is it possible to take VISA for Canada for me & my child **from USA**?

Yes, it is. In fact you can apply in two ways:

1. [Online](http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp)
2. [At the nearest Visa Application Center](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/vac.asp)

If you have any further doubts, it will be best to phone or email the nearest [Visa Application Center- contact details and locations found here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/vac.asp).

Answer (score 1):

[Immigration and Citizenship Canada has a website where you can find out your visa requirements for visiting Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/cometocanada.asp). If you answer the questions it will tell you what your requirements are. [Here is the website to apply for a visitor visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp). Application can be done online, so it seems unlikely that you need to be in your home country.