# Is it possible to travel to Canada using a US visa?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, canada, b1-b2-visas

I am an Indian and I'm going to get a B1 visa for the US within a couple of days. I will be traveling to Seattle. Is there any possibility of traveling to Canada-Vancouver with this visa from Seattle? Or do I need to apply for a tourist visa from India?

I am looking to travel to Canada from the US for just a day.

Comment: Canada does not have a visa exemption for people who have US visas.

Comment: I'm downvoting this, there are a bunch of similar questions like this - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25738/visa-for-canada-from-usa-for-a-bangladeshi

Answer (score 4):

Canada is a different country with its own visa requirements. As an Indian national, you would need to apply for a separate Canadian visa.

There are no reciprocal agreements between Canada and the US that allow for visa exemptions.

If you were to cross the border, you would likely be detained, denied entry, deported and possibly banned from entry to Canada.

Comment: While you would be denied entry, I think it unlikely that you would be detained, deported or banned. Canada is a bit nicer than that.

Comment: I would hope you would not "cross the border"... But rather, present yourself at the border post, do not allow the Canadian to wave you through, ask and be immediately upfront about your status, and ask who you speak to in order to gain permission to enter.

Comment: You would be formally denied entry; and detained (held) at the immigration point while they write up your entry attempt and then deported back. The ban is unlikely, but it does happen. I would agree though, given a choice, I would much rather deal with Canadian immigration than INS.

Comment: Presuming the crossing was attempted at a regular border point, it's far more likely that Canada would allow the OP to withdraw their request to enter Canada, and then return to the US rather than being formally denied/deported/etc.

Comment: @Doc If the border security show is any indication, their handguns and ammo would even be returned to them.

Comment: Canada does have visa exemptions for people with certain status in the US; it's just that holding a B visa does not qualify one for the exemption.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it's unlikely that a B visa holder would be legally in possession of a firearm or ammunition, so if the B visa holder had these things he or she might in fact be arrested.

Comment: INS weren't bad, DHS/TSA on the other hand... @DJClayworth they would detain you while completing the paperwork relating to your refused entry. And the associated questioning of course. Probably no ban unless you were a repeat customer of that process.

Comment: You are usually not even technically 'detained' during the questioning. Usually you can walk out of the questioning at any time by (as Doc says) deciding to "withdraw their request to enter Canada" . Assuming you are at a land border.